# How to insert new auto increment ID

Tags: php, mysql

I found the mysql_insert_id  function to retrieve the last auto generated ID.

Should I be using mysql_insert_id +1 to add a new ID or is there a call for adding a new unique ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using NULL for id:

```
INSERT INTO  `database`.`table` (`id`, `user`, `result`) VALUES (NULL, 'Alice', 'green')");
```

OR not specifying id at all:

```
INSERT INTO  `database`.`table` (`user`, `result`) VALUES ('Alice', 'green')");
```

Either way works just fine, more of a preference but personally I chose the second as its less typing.

Comment: And less confusing as well -- I'd expect the first example to throw an error, since you're trying to insert NULL into a (presumably) non-NULL column.  Or does mySQL not differentiate between unspecified and explicit NULL values?

Comment: NULL is acceptable here when you are using id as a primary key.

Comment: @steve no worries this is what stackoverflow is here for.  :-) cheers

Comment: better use DEFAULT instead of NULL

Comment: @AxelHeider why?

Comment: @Chris: it explicitly states to use the database defaults here and not a NULL value. So technically there is no strong reason, but it improves maintainability of the queries

Answer (score 3):

If your id field is set to auto increment, you don't have to add an ID at all. It will be incremented and added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL does exactly what it sounds like. When you insert a new record it will automatically generate a new ID for you. You do not need a separate call.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new record and set the auto-increment column to NULL, or just omit it entirely (which is implicitly setting it to NULL - it has the same result). The column will be set to the next auto-increment value instead of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a row and you insert again an another row, the new inserted id is not the same as what you delete before you insert again. example you have 3 row and the id value is 1, 2, 3, when you delete 3 then insert again, the id result is 4. And when you try to delete 2, the id result when you try insert again is 5.