# Insert auto-incremented ID using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, insert, prepared-statement

When inserting a new record into a table with an auto-incrementing ID column, it is normally enough to give the ID field the value NULL or omit it from the INSERT query, as explained at [How to insert new auto increment ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567955/how-to-insert-new-auto-increment-id)

```
INSERT INTO  `database`.`table` (`id`, `user`, `result`) VALUES (NULL, 'Alice', 'green')");
```

or

```
INSERT INTO  `database`.`table` (`user`, `result`) VALUES ('Alice', 'green')");
```

My question is - how do you do the same thing when using prepared statements. I have tried the following, using NULL:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `db` (id, name, password, text) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $password, $text);
$stmt->execute();
```

and the fowllowing, omitting the ID field:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_db` (name, password, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $password, $text);
$stmt->execute();
```

When I run this I get nothing inserted and no error message in the browser. I think it is because it is trying to insert a duplicate value for the ID field (stackoverflow.com/questions/12179770/…) - but why it should do that when this seems equivalent to the non-prepared-statement way of inserting data, and then give no message, I'm not sure.

Any ideas most welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by "neither worked?"  What happened?

Comment: prepared statements has nothing to do with literal NULLs in the query. Your problem is somewhere else

Comment: I get nothing inserted and no error message in the browser. I think it is because it is trying to insert a duplicate value for the ID field (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179770/mysql-1062-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-primary) - but why it should do that when this seems equivalent to the non-prepared-statement way of inserting data, and then give no message, I'm not sure.

Comment: `no error message in the browser.` - You didn't ask for it. Here you are: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15447204/285587

Comment: Thanks, Your Common Sense - the link led to ` ... or trigger_error($mysqli->error)`, which confirmed it was the duplicate primary key problem. The database structure had got altered so auto_increment no longer worked. After re-initializing the database, all is now well.