# Why isn't my insert working using prepared statements?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just recently learned that prepared statements are more suitable method to use than previous deprecated methods.

I tried to the best of my ability and online tutorials to make this work and find out the problem, but I've had no luck, so here I am, asking for help.

```
 <?php 
 $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Mylife2015") or die ("Couldn't   
 connect to SQL server");
 mysql_select_db("i-neo") or die("Couldn't select DB");

 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
 $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
 }
 else {
 $user = "";
 }


 $d  = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', time());

 if(isset($_POST['log'])){
 $man = $_POST['artist_name'];
 $an = $_POST['album_name'];
 $sn = $_POST['song_name'];
 foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $name_tmp){
     $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
     $tmpnm = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
     $type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
     $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
     $dir = "uploads/".$name;
     $move = move_uploaded_file($tmpnm,$dir);
     if($move){
        $msi = $query = "INSERT INTO music ($user, $man, $an, $sn, $name, 
 $type, $size, $dir, $d) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
             $stmt = $db->prepare($msi);
             $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $user, $man, $an, $sn, $name, 
 $type, $size, $dir, $d);
             $stmt->execute();
        if($msi){
            echo "<script>alert('Insert Successful')</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Upload Fail')</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Uploaded Successfully')</script>";
    }
 }

 }
 ?>
```

This is my form:

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <p>
    <label> Song</label>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" />
 </p>

 <p>
    <label> Artist Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="artist_name" />
 </p>

 <p>
    <label> Album Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="album_name" />
 </p>

 <p>
    <label> Song Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="song_name" />
 </p>

 <p>
    <input type="submit" name="log" value="Upload" />
 </p>
```

This is my database table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `music` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `artist_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `audio_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `album_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
   `type` varchar(71) NOT NULL,
   `size` double NOT NULL,
   `directory` varchar(71) NOT NULL,
   `date_uplaoded` datetime NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: `mysql_` doesn't have prepared statements so that connection method is invalid.

Comment: Another Doh, there coming thick and fast today @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly Let's call it *Fantastic Friday, Smokey*

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean? so if I can't use mysql_ which is deprecated, what am I suppose to use?

Comment: the same MySQL API as the rest of your code. ;-) unlike different funky pieces of clothing, those don't mix and match.

Comment: @RiggsFolly don't need to be rude about it...not everyone has knowledge, that's why you pass down information, so please say only relevant things...gosh some people...

Comment: I was talkin to Fred, not you

Comment: oh and a possible typo for your column creation `date_uplaoded` double check that if what's being passed in your query as `date_uploaded` ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're talking to Fred about me - clearly, so please remove yourself from my posts if you're not going to put in some effort to help[, just flagged you as rude. This isn't a chatting service to chat to your friends, you have other social networking sites for that.

Comment: and `, $dir, $d);` that `$d` could be replaced with `NOW()` saving you a declaration and a few keystrokes ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could I ask a huge favour please Freed? Would you be kind enough to give me a link to a guide I can use or have a look at to do inserts? Of course without using deprecated methods and without prepared statements which as you said don't work with what I'm using. That'd be absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `prepared statements` with msql_ which doesn't support them, you need to establish your connection the following way:

```
    <?php
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "username";
            $password = "password";
            $dbname = "yourdbname";

            // Create connection
            $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
            if ($db->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
            }

           // prepare and bind
      $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (name, fatherame, add)   VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $fathername, $add);

    // set parameters and execute
    $name = "Muneer Khan";
    $fathername = "Shabbir Khan";
    $add = "KingsStreet";
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    ?>
```

> OR you could also use PDO this way:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$db = "yourdbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db", $user, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (name, fathername, add)
    VALUES (:name, :fathername, :add)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fathername', $fathername);
    $stmt->bindParam(':add', $add);

    $name = "Muneer Khan";
    $fathername = "Shabbir Khan";
    $add = "KingsStreet";
    $stmt->execute();
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$db = null;
?>
```

Comment: Answers starting with *try this*  really need something to back that up with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Give me a second!

Comment: Now *that* makes a lot more sense ;-)

Comment: Or you can use PDO if you prefer

Comment: That's what I prefer @RiggsFolly

Comment: @Fred-ii- See, If I got that correct?

Comment: I was in the middle of editing to change all `$conn` to `$db` since that is what the OP is using, but I won't touch it. Edit: Looks ok to me. Edit 2: nope. See comment below...

Comment: Oops, actually, you're declaring your variables *after* your binds. Those should come first.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You can always edit, that would surely help me learn better! :)

Comment: Oh sure I could, but I can't so I won't lol - OP has comments to go on. I'm just being a bystander here ;-)

Comment: lol well. ship it, if it works right? :P

Comment: this is great!!! thank you so much! I have a basic question, what if the first field in my table is ID which obviously is auto increment, does that effect how I should do the inserts?

Comment: @Hedi leave it empty or don't even put it in the `query`. It's `AI`, you don't have to do anything as such. :)

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari awesome, so if it's "id, name, fathername, add" in the table, i would just have to put (?,?,?)

Comment: @Hedi you either leave it empty or dont even `mention` it. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592545/insert-auto-incremented-id-using-prepared-statements?lq=1